# ORA-00907: parêntese direito não encontrado

Tags: sql, python, oracle

Olá, faz pouco tempo que estou trabalhando com o oracle, e estou tendo esse problema na query, me retorna o erro: ORA-00907: parêntese direito não encontrado, segue abaixo a mesma:

```python
("""select 
                ordem.id,ordem.data_prog,ordem.rms, ordem.pkpk, medida.ganho,ponto.descricao as ponto, unidade.id as id_unid, unidade.id_segmento as segmento,equipamento.id as id_equipamento,codigo.id, codigo.descricao
                from intranet.vb_item_ordem_servico ordem

                join intranet.vb_ponto_medida medida on medida.id = ordem.id_ponto_medida
                join intranet.vb_ponto ponto on ponto.id = medida.id_vb_ponto
                join intranet.gm_arvore arvore on arvore.id = ponto.id_arvore
                join intranet.cd_unidade unidade on unidade.id = arvore.id_unidade
                join intranet.gm_equipamento_arvore equipamento on equipamento.id = arvore.id
                join intranet.ce_tipo_equipamento codigo on codigo.id = equipamento.id_tipo_equipamento

                where (ordem.data_prog between date_sub(to_date('{}', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), INTERVAL {} MONTH) and to_date('{}', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) AND codigo.id='{}' """).format(data_prog, intervalo,data_prog, id)
```

Alguem poderia me dizer onde estou errando.

Desde de já agradeço

Comment: Aquelas 3 aspas no inicio estão corretas?

Comment: Nessa parte não tem um parêntese a mais no final? and to_date('{}', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))

Comment: Qual é o conteúdo de `data_prog`, `intervalo` e `id`?

Comment: Victor, são parâmetros que o usuário informa no script (python),  data_prog, intervalo e id são declarados como string.

Comment: Leia sobre [**injeção de SQL**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço o Oracle, mas o seu `where` tem um parenteses direito ')' que não "casa" com ninguem, coloque em um terminal qt-console (acho que funciona no ipython tambem) e vá navegando na linha de codigo e os parenteses de abertura e fechamento são destacados, fiz isso com o seu `where` e com o da resposta do Rapahel e encontrei (em ambos) um parenteses de fechamento "solteiro".

```
where (ordem.data_prog between date_sub(to_date('{}', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), INTERVAL {} MONTH) and to_date('{}', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) AND codigo.id='{}' """).format(data_prog, intervalo,data_prog, id)

).format(data_prog, intervalo,data_prog, id)
^
Esse parenteses está "solteiro"
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja se da certo. Acho que o parentese da primeira condição do where estava no lugar errado.

```
("""select ordem.id,ordem.data_prog,ordem.rms, ordem.pkpk, medida.ganho,ponto.descricao as ponto, unidade.id as id_unid, unidade.id_segmento as segmento,equipamento.id as id_equipamento,codigo.id, codigo.descricao
            from intranet.vb_item_ordem_servico ordem
            join intranet.vb_ponto_medida medida on medida.id = ordem.id_ponto_medida
            join intranet.vb_ponto ponto on ponto.id = medida.id_vb_ponto
            join intranet.gm_arvore arvore on arvore.id = ponto.id_arvore
            join intranet.cd_unidade unidade on unidade.id = arvore.id_unidade
            join intranet.gm_equipamento_arvore equipamento on equipamento.id = arvore.id
            join intranet.ce_tipo_equipamento codigo on codigo.id = equipamento.id_tipo_equipamento
            where ordem.data_prog between date_sub(to_date('{}', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), INTERVAL {} MONTH) and to_date('{}', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
            AND codigo.id='{}' """).format(data_prog, intervalo,data_prog, id)
```